# Use a Twig filter to resize / crop images in templates

Tags: 8, theming

I want to use a twig filter to resize/crop images in Drupal 8 templates for responsive images, I know I can generate responsive images with Image Style and Responsive Image styles, but that requires too much clicking in 3 different configuration pages.

I would prefer something like:

```
<img 
srcset="{{ image_url|crop(1000, 1000) }} 1000w, {{ image_url|crop(500, 500) }} 
500w,"
sizes="..."
src="{{ image_url|crop(1000, 1000) }}"/>
```

Or something like LiipImagineBundle https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/basic-usage.html

Does somebody know if it's possible to use it with Drupal 8

Comment: Drupal answers is a place for answers that are not primarily opinion based. As you are asking how something should be done in a non-Drupal way (which you have indicated you are not interested in), you're essentially asking for people to give opinions, which does not match the format of Drupal answers. You would be better to post this on Drupal.org which is more suited to discussion.

Comment: Use image styles. Changes won’t require code updates.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After some research I found this is possible using Image Styles and [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

I created 2 image styles scale and crop:

- scale_crop_1000_1000
- scale_crop_500_500

It is something like this:

```
<img srcset="{{ node.field_image.entity.uri.value | image_style('scale_crop_1000_1000') } 1000w, 
{{ node.field_image.entity.uri.value | image_style('scale_crop_500_500') } 500w",
sizes="..."
src="{{ node.field_image.entity.uri.value | image_style('scale_crop_1000_1000') }" />
```